# How to access Angular 2 router in Meter.call() method

Tags: angular, angular2-meteor

I am designing a simple login screen using Angular2-Meteor, I want to redirect user to /dashboard once login API call is successful.

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {MeteorComponent} from 'angular2-meteor';
import {LocalStorageService} from '../services/localstorage.service'
import {Router} from '@angular/router-deprecated';
import {LoggerService} from "../services/loggerService";

'use strict';
@Component({
    selector: 'login',
    templateUrl: 'client/login/login.html',
    bindings: [LoggerService]
})

export class LoginComponent extends MeteorComponent {

public loginData = {
    username: '',
    password: ''
};

constructor(private _logger:LoggerService, public router:Router) {
    super();
}

login() {
    this._logger.log('Login attempted ', this.loginData);

    this.call('authenticateUser', this.loginData.username, this.loginData.password , function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            this._logger.error(err);

        } else {

            console.info(JSON.parse(data));
            console.log(this.router);
            this.router.navigate(['Dashboard'])
        }
      });
    }
}
```

I am not able to access the router in `Meteor.call()`.
I have tried passing `this` reference to `Meteor.call` by doing `self = this`, but it takes `self`as `Window`.

Can someone please help with this?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the arrow function to have the same `this` context within a class.

Change your anonymous callback function like this:

```
this.call('authenticateUser', 
          this.loginData.username, 
          this.loginData.password, 
          (err, data) => {
   //...
});
```

*hint*

Try to look into `promises` or `observables` instead of using a callback function

Answer (score 2):

You can bind the function to your context like this:

```
this.call('authenticateUser', this.loginData.username, this.loginData.password , function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        this._logger.error(err);

    } else {

        console.info(JSON.parse(data));
        console.log(this.router);
        this.router.navigate(['Dashboard'])
    }
  }).bind(this);
```

Or you could just use an arrow function:

```
this.call('authenticateUser', this.loginData.username, this.loginData.password , (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
        this._logger.error(err);

    } else {
        console.info(JSON.parse(data));
        console.log(this.router);
        this.router.navigate(['Dashboard'])
    }
}).bind(this);
```